# expected statement in html line

Tags: excel, vba

the strBody below will be shown in a html body in an outlook email from excel, but i get an expected statement error and i cant seem to find the fix to the error

```
strBody = "<BODY>Cell(s) " & Target.Address(False, False) & _
        " were modified on " & _
        Format$(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy") & " at " & Format$(Now, "hh:mm:ss") & _
        " by " & Environ$("username") &_
        "<br> <br> Select the Invoicing Tab in the <a href="http://www.google.com">Workbook</a></BODY>"
```

Comment: You need to pad the double quotes `<a href=""http://www.google.com"">`

Comment: Also  `" by " & Environ$("username") &_` should be `" by " & Environ$("username") & _`. Notic the space between "&" and "_" in the end?